# How to run MAUI Blazor App in a web browser?

Tags: blazor, maui, maui-blazor

How can I run a MAUI Blazor App in a web browser?
I've used the VS MAUI with Blazor sample project

Comment: You don't. You run `Blazor` itself in a web browser - see [Blazor docs](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor). The purpose of `Maui Blazor` is to allow you to re-use Blazor HTML/CSS/C# inside a Maui app (for mobile or desktop), so that you have *some* sharing between your web browser code, and your app code.

Comment: If the reason you want to do this is in order to use the developer tools to help inspect elements, then see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/developer-tools?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=windows

Answer (score 11):

When you first hear MAUI Blazor, it's easy to think "web app running in a desktop/mobile app." That's what I thought, and I'm sure that's what many others thought. It turns out MAUI Blazor is more along the lines of "native desktop/mobile app that was developed using Blazor/Razor syntax instead of XAML."

So the short answer is no, you can't run a MAUI Blazor app in a web browser.

Originally, there were basically two basic models for hosting Blazor, Blazor Server and Blazor WASM (Web Assembly). At the time of this post, MAUI Blazor uses a third kind of hosting model, Blazor Hybrid. Blazor Hybrid is a completely different hosting model. With Hybrid, you get access to native capabilities of the deivce. This means you need a different codebase for each target platform (Android, Apple, Windows, etc). Because your Hybrid codebase can target and rely upon platform-specific functionality, you can't just move MAUI Blazor to a web app.

If you design your app carefully, creating a Blazor Server or Blazor WASM app using your MAUI Blazor components shouldn't be too difficult. If you're really careful, you may need almost no code changes. But simply running MAUI Blazor in a web browser is not possible.

[Relevant MSDN article on Blazor hosting models.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Came here and saw this and leaving dissappointed. I really thought this was the best of both worlds. Web deployed to my IIS Server and Mobile deployed to my clients mobile platforms. 

Not really sure who uses desktop apps in 2024

Comment: @CodeMan03 Having designed several MAUI apps targeting multiple platforms, I will say that if you start with the intention of deploying on multiple platforms, it's relatively straightforward. A good rule is place ALL Razor components, including MainLayouts, in a separate Razor Class Library. Then, you can simply reference the MainLayout from the class library in any type of project (Blazor, MAUI, etc). If you didn't start out this way though you're in trouble.

Comment: @CodeMan03 also worth mentioning that good Blazor apps are really close to mobile platform native apps these days. There are a few gotchas, but for most use cases, a Blazor app can do basically everything a native device app can do. My hope is that native mobile device apps become as rare as desktop apps in the coming decade.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried MAUI yet, but isn't it the other way round. MAUI Blazor is supposed to allow you to use Blazor Components inside a MAUI app.

This basically gives you the Blazor Binding magic instead of the XAML Binding magic, while still giving you access to device specific functions (e.g. on Mobile you can check wether you have a network connection or GPS or whatever)

I might be wrong though

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible without some code changes (extracting blazor code to razor library and reference it into Web and Maui project)

But hopefully in .NET 9 this could be implemented:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4528

Answer (score -1):

After asking my question I did review possible answers that are already available.  I found one that hit the nail on the head.  My answer is NO - you cannot use XAML in a Blazor Web application. You can create a Native application with Blazor MAUI that runs on Windows and mixes Blazor/Razor pages that use html and css along with pages that use XAML and C#.

Comment: Your answer just repeats what others have already said.

Answer (score -8):

when u run maui blazor on windows it already open it on Edge Browser .. u can do print and inspect content