# Is there no existing way to run a MAUI Blazor App in the browser?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui-blazor

From what I have read and understood, MAUI Blazor is a technology that allows to create applications for web, Android, iOS, Windows, MacCatalyst and Tizen, but when creating a project I don't see anywhere a way to run the project in the browser, I really think there should be some way to run a MAUI Blazor App in the browser while developing and not only when hosting. If I have misunderstood the way MAUI Blazor works please explain me.

I was creating a MAUI App, then I switched to MAUI Blazor App to make the same web project as well, but I can't find how to go about viewing it in the browser while developing it.

Comment: Hello, you could refer to this question: [How to run MAUI Blazor App in a web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72323525/how-to-run-maui-blazor-app-in-a-web-browser).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.