# Can BlazorWebView download the Blazor code from a server?

Tags: blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I am working on an old client/server kiosk system.  It was designed where most of the code that changed regularly was all on the server. The Kiosk code was a C++ program that hosted the WebControl and downloaded the core app from the server.

The kiosk needs to be rewritten and a MAUI Blazor hybrid is being considered.  The only question is whether or not the Blazor components (the core app) could live on the server and the BlazorWebView in the MAUI app download the Blazor components from the server, or... do the Blazor components need to be embedded in MAUI application?

Comment: You can refer to the answer of this case: [How to run MAUI Blazor App in a web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73866515/19902734).